# I have written one java program. Need a solution to print the Haemoglobin count in print

Tags: java

```
package oopsconcepts;

public class ReturnMethod {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String Result=findHaemoglobin(12);
        displayHaemoglobin(Result);

        Result=findHaemoglobin(8);
        displayHaemoglobin(Result);

    }


    public static String findHaemoglobin(int count) {

        String Result;
        if(count<=8) {
            Result="Very Low";
        }
        else if(count >=8 && count <=10) {
            Result="Low";
        }
        else if(count >=10 && count <=12) {
            Result="OK, Can be improved";
        }
        else if(count >=12 && count <=15) {
            Result="Excellent";
        }
        else {Result="NA"; }
        return Result;



    }

    public static void displayHaemoglobin(String Result) {


        System.out.println("Haemoglobin count" + " " + "signifies" + " " + Result); 
    }

}
```

I want to print the Haemoglobin count also in the print statement. I am returning the result which is getting printed successfully. But I need the count also. sample print out statement if I am sending 12 count should be,

"Haemoglobin count of 12 signifies OK, Can be improved. "

Answer (score 1):

You can add a second parameter to your displayHaemoglobin method and then use it in the System.out.println:

```
public static void displayHaemoglobin(String result, int count) {
    System.out.println("Haemoglobin count of " + count + " signifies" + " " + Result); 
}
```

The call to the method would be then (for example):

```
displayHaemoglobin(result, 8);
```

Answer (score 0):

make a instance variable to save count when you call the method.